# AWS - Writing policy to allow DeleteOnTermination only on EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, identity-management

I am executing below command from my ec2 instance. (instance id changed on purpose). I also tried the same command after installing aws-cli on my windows also. Same unauthorized error. I am mainly doing it to understand how policy creation works and took this as a task where i want to allow Modify-instance-attribute only if it has DeleteOnTermination set to false.

```
aws ec2 modify-instance-attribute --instance-id i-12345 --block-device-mappings "[{"DeviceName": "/dev/sda1","Ebs":{"DeleteOnTermination":false}}]"
```

I configured following below policies in multiple ways but its still giving me unauthorized error. I cannot define DeleteOnTermination to be false, it gives me Json syntax error.

Can someone help me to write it

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:ModifyInstanceAttribute",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEqualsIgnoreCase": {
                    "ec2:Attribute/blockDeviceMapping": "DeleteOnTermination"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

PS Edit

I was able to match on blockdevicemappings by using this string specifically.
"ec2:Attribute": "BlockDeviceMappings". I played around with different combinations of blockdevicemappings and finally got above right. But i cannot understand how to further extend this match to include DeleteOnTermination value as well. Please suggest

Comment: Since you are getting unauthorized error when you run the command using AWS CLI, ensure that you either configure CLI with user credentials with a policy that grants permissions to the appropriate EC2 instance or the instance where you run CLI has appropriate EC2 Role permissions.

Comment: And that advice holds whenever you restrict permissions in any way: remove the restriction and see if you can now perform that action. If you are still unable then you have deeper issues than the permissions being too narrow. If you can perform the action then you can start slowly restricting the access.

Comment: yes its not an issue of permission. I am able to do it if i dont give any conditions. In my edit to original post i am able to make change using the conditions also but i am not getting any idea how to further match DeleteOnTermination:False